# Deployed Express app to vercel and only working landing page not other routes

Tags: express, vercel

I have deployed my Node Express server side to `Vercel` but I am getting a problem. The landing page is working always. But other routes like `/users` or any other routes are working at the first time. After that even though the landing page is working other routes are not.

the following is the first time I hit the url and was getting the results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8kks.png

Later on I hit the same url and am getting the following error:

```
Cannot GET /users:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZcOJ.png

my network is giving 404 status code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzGb7.png

my vercel.json is as following:

```
{
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone please help me out solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this was a network issue. I faced the same issue. I tried many ways to solve this for hours. And finally I noticed that my VPN extension was turned on. After turning off the VPN extension it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, created Rest API service, then when trying to open routes it gives this `404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used router like below.

```
app.post("/api/pull-scale", function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

So I meet error like you.But I resolve this bug.

```
app.post("/pull-scale", function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```